# How to create dataframe from index and array

Tags: python, pandas

I have an `array`and `index`

`array=array([1,2,3])`

`index=Index(['A','B','C'],dtype='object')`

I'd like to concat them and create`dataframe` like following

`df`

```
column   data
A         1
B         2
C         3
```

I tried

pd.concat([index.array])

But didn't work well. How can I achieve them?

Thanks

Comment: _But didn't work well._ What does that mean? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. Have you looked at the Pandas documentation?

Comment: Try : ``pd.DataFrame({"column": index, "data": array})``

Answer (score 0):

Let us try

```
pd.Series(array,index=index).to_frame('data')
Out[144]: 
   data
A     1
B     2
C     3
```